# Restkit not work on iOS 7

Tags: ios7, restkit-0.20

I'm using the restkit to make the request that returns JSON Data. It worked fine on iOS 6 but when i built the app on XCode 5 + iOS 7, it cannot get the response data.

```
[objectManager getObjectsAtPath:path parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *
     operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult){

} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation * operation, NSError *error) {
    //always run to this block

}];
```

Here's the error log:

```
E restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:575 Object request 
failed: Underlying HTTP     request operation failed with error: 
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost.
```

Anyone helps?

Comment: iOS 7 and Xcode are still under NDA which restricts you from talking about it outside of the official Apple Developer Forum.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about iOS 7 which is under NDA (please use the Apple forum).

Comment: This is unlikely to be related to iOS 7. What else changed at the same time? What did you change during migration? Look at these factors.

Comment: I just tried my app that uses restkit on an iOS 7 iPad and the app runs but when I try to authenticate with my server I always get a 401 (authorization failed). I have no idea why this is. Going to try and fix that today, I'll keep you posted if I find any solutions.