# "The network connection was lost" when loading a specific Resource

Tags: objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

since a few days I have problems with RestKit 0.20

RestKit is included via CocoaPods so it is up to date. I am developing an app for iOS7 and this problems happen on all real and simulated devices.

When I am loading a resource like an image or a pdf file like this:

```
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [self.restManager objectManager];
[objectManager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:@"image/jpeg"];
[[objectManager HTTPClient] getPath:path parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    if (completeBlock) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:responseObject];
        completeBlock(image);
    }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    if (failBlock) {
        failBlock(error);
    }
}];
```

I get this error message:

```
T restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:148 GET 'https://***/attachment/11787':
request.headers={
    Accept = "*";
    "Accept-Language" = "en-US";
    Authorization = "***";
    "User-Agent" = "***";
}
request.body=(null)
E restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:174 GET 'https://***/attachment/11787' (200 OK) [1.0048 s]:
error=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo=0xf7ba400 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https:/***/attachment/11787, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://***/attachment/11787, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost., NSUnderlyingError=0x1605c930 "The network connection was lost."}
response.body=(null)
```

But this is not the common case for all resources but for only a few. The other resources get loaded at the same time (The requests were added to the queue at the same time).

Once this error happends for a resource, the resource will never get loaded again but failing with the same error message.

I cleaned the cache and deleted the app, so it shouldn't be a problem with caching or something like that. And there is no difference if http or https is used.

Similar to this question (without solution): [Restkit not work on iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378717/restkit-not-work-on-ios-7)

Do you have any ideas, what I am doing wrong or what causes this behaviour?

Comment: Just as an FYI, [RestKit is on 0.22.0](http://beta.cocoapods.org/?q=restkit). You may want to update your pod. No clue if this will solve your problem, but if you don't have a requirement for it to be on 0.20, I'd say give it a try.

Comment: How many requests are you making at the same time (should be <= 5). Why are you using the object managers http client for the image download (instead of a dedicated http client)?

Comment: @jprofitt: You are right. I adapted my Podfile, now it's 0.22.0. Unfortunately, it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Wain: Well, much more than 5 requests are added, but this limit says that only 5 request are executed concurrent, or am I wrong?

Comment: I say you should limit to 5, but I see nothing in your code to tell me you're doing it. You need to set the limit on the http client operation queue.

Comment: Ok, i limited the number of request. I thought this is a default value. Sadly, still the same problem. I debuged a bit, and saw that I get an OK as response and a content-length of 10048 bytes. In the corresponding AFURLConnectionOperation the _totalBytesRead is 10048. So the file is loaded completely...